# What is url-validation regex and what is it used for?

Tags: regex, url-validation

A person I know told me that Javascript files with URL validation codes are malicious.

My questions are:

- What is URL validation and what is it used for?
- What does regex have to do with it, and is it bad to use regex for this task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**URL validation** checks if a given text is a URL or not.
Such a check is often performed when a user has to enter a URL on a web form, to ensure that the entered text corresponds to a URL.

Since you have **regex** in your tags: Why is using **regex** bad for this? Because many people don't read [the full URL specification](https://url.spec.whatwg.org) when writing their regex. For example, have a look [at this post](https://mathiasbynens.be/demo/url-regex) in which many different regex that are used out in the wild are compared, and how they fail.